# C++ Run Batch File Without Redirecting Output

Tags: c++, batch-file, createprocess

```
tempString = (string("cmd.exe /C \"") + tempString + "\"");

STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

CreateProcess(NULL, (LPSTR)tempString.c_str(), 0, 0, FALSE, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, NULL, 0, &si, &pi);
```

I am starting a batch script from within another process through a dll.
The issue is that the process is displaying:

> error : Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process
>   immediately.

How can I start a batch script so that it is independent of the calling process (will not close when callee closes) and does not output in the console of the calling process?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25677154/3959875)

Comment: @wOxxOm DETATCH_PROCESS didn't work, but I read the other available flags and CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE does work in my situation, thanks.

Comment: it'd be nice if you add your findings as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want show the console window when executing command string, you can do as below:

```
tempString = (string(" /C \"") + tempString + "\"");
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "cmd.exe", tempString.c_str(), NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: `WinExec` was deprecated long time ago and should not be used. It exists only for the compatibility with 16bit applications.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I forget the WinExec API is deprecated, I modified my answer.

Comment: My question wasn't to hide the window, it was to prevent the redirection of output.

Answer (score 0):

The `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag allocates a new console for the process to use so that it does not use the same stdout as the calling process.